# Eclipse crashes on start raspberry pi

Tags: eclipse

Im having a problem with eclipse on my raspberry pi running jessie 8. It shows the little splash screen then instantly crashes. Here is the log

`!SESSION Sun Oct 16 17:21:05 CDT 2016 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2016-10-16 17:21:06.039
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)`
 Any help is apperciated.

Comment: Looks like a wrong Eclipse installation. How did you install it?

Comment: sudo apt-get install eclipse

Comment: Do you have the same problem with latest version from the official site?

Comment: I cannot run it from the site I've tried several times it never opens

Comment: How do I completely uninstall it?

Comment: sudo apt-get remove eclipse

Comment: I did that and then did sudo apt-get install eclipse and Im still getting the same crash I may just backup my workspace and delete all eclipse files I can by hand

Comment: The workspace has nothing to do with the installation, it should be intact. If you installed using apt-get the way to uninstall is to use apt-get, otherwise you will get a broken package.

Comment: In any case what error are you getting from official Eclipse?

Comment: No error just doesnt open plain and simple no message nothing, but I tried uninstalling and reinstalling eclipse and still got the exact same error

Comment: If you could send me a link to the official one that works with the rpi that would be nice.

Comment: Sorry I don't know.

Comment: I finally got it to open after reinstalling like 3 times but seems it cannot find my jdk.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I had to reinstall Rasbian due to some file I think corrupting itself

Comment: Update after reinstalling eclipse it still seems not to be able to find the jdk as java key defined words such as if and I cannot make a java specific project

Comment: Eclipse doesn't find the JDK by itself. You need to manually specify where the JDK is in the settings. Anyway this is another question entirely, your original question has been resolved I think. Please note this is not a forum.

Comment: Ok I will ask a new one but thanks for your help